# How to upload image file in alfresco using PHP

Tags: php, alfresco, cmis

I want to upload image file into alfresco using cmis api using PHP..
I can create simple text document in alfresco using following code

```
$obs = $client->createDocument($myfolder->id, $repo_new_file,$prop, "testssss", "text/plain");
```

I tried following code to upload image

```
$obs = $client->createDocument($myfolder->id, $repo_new_file,$prop, null, "image/jpeg");
```

But can't create image file into alfresco

Can anyone help me to solve this issue ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem

Just store base64 content into image.. Use below code

```
$filename="A.jpg";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
if(!$handle)return FALSE;
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
if(!$mimetype)$type=mime_content_type($filename);
else $type=$mimetype;
fclose($handle);
$base64_content=base64_encode($contents);
$obs = $client->createDocument($myfolder->id, $repo_new_file,$prop, base64_decode($base64_content), "image/jpg");
```